# Is there a command which creates a temporary file containing the arguments passed to it?

Tags: shell, command-line, files, tmp

I can paste the contents of a file into a command using `cat` and backticks:

```
ls `cat filenames`
```

Is there a way to do the reverse - to turn a string into a (temporary) filename?

```
gcc -o cpuburn `uncat "main(){while(1);}"`.c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the source code on gcc's standard input. Since `gcc` isn't given a file name, you need the `-x` option to let it know what the output language is. You can pass input via a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) (most convenient for a single line), a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents), or a pipe.

```
gcc -o cpuburn -x c - <<<'main(){while(1);}'
```

If you need a file name on the command line, you can use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to generate the content. That doesn't give you control over the file name (it'll be something like `/dev/fd/42`).

```
gcc -o cpuburn -x c <(echo 'main(){while(1);}')
```

If you really need control over the temporary file's name, you'll need something more complex where you manually create and remove the temporary file.

```
src=$(mktemp XXXXXXXXXX.c)
trap 'rm "$src"' EXIT INT TERM HUP
echo 'main(){while(1);}' >"$src"
gcc -o cpuburn "$src"
```

(This answer assumes that your shell is bash, zsh or ksh93.)

Comment: I'd suggest using `<<` instead of `<<<` or `<(…)`, though, since it should be the way more portable way to do it (and the much easier in terms of quoting etc., too).